# NSLog gives runtime error

Tags: objective-c, runtime-error, nslog

Ok, so I know I can just leave out the NSLog but why does it give me a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error?

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex2
{

    if(buttonIndex2 == 0 && waitForAction == NO)
    {
        waitForAction = YES;
        [self showAbortAlert];
        NSLog(@"%@",buttonIndex2); //This one does not crash the app

    } else if (buttonIndex2 == 1 && waitForAction == NO)
    {
        waitForAction = YES;
        [self addObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",buttonIndex2); //This one crashes the app
    } //else if
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the method signature again

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex2
```

buttonIndex2 is of type `NSInteger`. If you do `%@` in NSLog your code is calling the `description` method on the object. But buttonIndex2 is not an object.

use `NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex2);`

The first one (with buttonIndex == 0) does not crash the app because you are calling `description` on an object at memory address 0, which is basically the same as `[nil description]` and this is perfectly legal in Objective-C.

Comment: or `%i` (my personal preference cause I think int not decimal).

Answer (score 2):

Use `%d` as it is an integer, `%@` is for strings...

```
NSLog(@"%d", buttonIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

buttonIndex2 is an integer use :

```
NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex2);
```

And go read some good book on C.